Change characters of an original variable in zsh given as a reference to the variable name
For some zsh cheatsheet, I am investigating (indirect) variable references. I have a scalar variable and a reference to it:
scal='Some value'        
scalRef=scal  

Using scalRef alone, I can get everything I want to know about scal via the indirect parameter expansion flag (P) of zsh:
echo Value: ${(P)scalRef} 
echo Length State Type: ${(P)#scalRef} ${(P)+scalRef} ${(Pt)scalRef}  

I can easily get characters and substrings, too:
echo First char: ${${(P)scalRef}[1]} 
echo Substring: ${${(P)scalRef}[6,-1]}  

To assign another value to the original variable, one can use parameter expansion like this:
: ${(P)scalRef::='New value'} 
echo scal: $scal  

Another clever way would be:
typeset "${scalRef}"='Other value' 
echo scal: $scal

The QUESTION now is: How to change single characters or slices in the original variable? Of course, eval should not be used. I tried:
: ${(P)scalRef[1,5]::='Cool'} 
echo scal: $scal  

but it does not change anything, even though no error is reported. I was expecting Cool value. So, what happens here? Also:
: ${${(P)scalRef}[1,5]::='Unknown'}    
echo scal: $scal  

but this attempt produces an error: no identifier. Expected: Unknown value. Of course, getting the entire original value, make the change, and replace the value of the original variable is a practical workaround. But maybe, zsh parameter expansion has an idiomatic answer.

maybe with : ${(P)scalRef::=Unknown${${(P)scalRef}[6,-1]}}?

What version of zsh are you using? With : ${(P)scalRef[1,5]::='Cool'}, I see scal being assigned the value Cool in 5.7.1. (Which is still not what you want, but it's something.)

@chepner: I have zsh 5.7.1, too. And yes, I see that scal gets the value Cool assigned, too. However, after scal='Some data';  : ${scal[1,4]::='Cool'}; echo $scal I am getting Cool data, which is the expected result. So in the absence of (P) the ::= operator is compatible with subscripting.

@Fravadona: Great!  After scal='Some data'; index=5; newstr=' nice '; : ${(P)scalRef::=${${(P)scalRef}[1,index-1]}$newstr${${(P)scalRef}[index+1,-1]}}; echo $scalI am seeing
Some nice data, indeed. So that's the workaround I mentioned, as a compact one-liner.

With arrays, you can use set: s=(a b c d); sr=s; set -A $sr'[2,3]' 4 5 6; s will then be ( a 4 5 6 d ). However, it does not appear to work with strings.

With the P flag at the same level of nesting as the ::= assignment, after transforming the reference parameter to include the desired subscript:
ref=var var='Some value'
: ${(P)${ref/%/[1,4]}::='Cool'}
echo $var

That should output Cool value.
typeset can also be used with a subscript:
typeset $ref\[1,4]=Cool

